# Is there a good one hand typing Mac app?

Tags: macos, mac, software-recommendation

Is there a (decent) Mac app that I could use to learn one handed typing?

Comment: I am a visually impaired vet and have been to multiple blind vet centers, I am a moderator for a support group for iOS. I met a vet a few years ago who lost both hands and vision in Viet Nam, the input method he used was Morse Code, the input method was side to side paddle. I did a search on the app store they have a few apps one being Morse Mania which is a teaching as well as an input method using the mouse. I don't know his WPM but he seemed very quick. Not knowing what your needs are but have you thought about voice dictation.

Comment: If no one comes up with a better alternative I would be glad to contact the VA and see if they have a better method.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The reason for one hand typing is due to my work. In AutoCAD, for one thing, it is better to type one handed for the different commands. One hand on the mouse, one on the keyboard. I use two hands right now, but would like to be flexible.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is a program on the app store for this!

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mirror-qwerty-one-hand-typing/id496021762?mt=12

[image: An screenshot of the Mirror QWERTY software]

Answer (score 0):

This is a good free alternative:
https://github.com/ZevEisenberg/Keyb